# NoMethodError with .chr.to_i

Tags: ruby, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive method sum_of_digits(i) that takes the sum of integers, i.e. '456' = 4+5+6 = 15

However, I receive a NoMethodError for chr.to_i in the following code:

```
def sum_of_digits(i)
  input = i.to_s
  if i == 0
    return 0
  elsif input.length == 1
    return i
  else
    for n in 1..input.length
      sum += input[i].chr.to_i % 10^(n-1)   
    end
  end
  return sum
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

String indexes are zero-based in ruby. The problem is here:

```
for n in 1..input.length
```

it should be written as

```
for n in 0..input.length-1
```

BTW, call to `chr` is superfluous as well, since you already have a string representation of a digit there. As well, `sum` must be declared in advance and set to zero.

---

Also, the whole code is not ruby idiomatic: one should avoid using unnecessary `return`s and `for`-loop. The modified version (just in case) would be:

```
def sum_of_digits(i)
  input = i.to_s
  case
  when i == 0 then 0 # return zero
  when input.length == 1 then i # return i
  else
    sum = 0
    input.length.times do |index|
      sum += input[index].to_i % 10^index   
    end
    sum
  end
end
```

or, even better, instead of

```
    sum = 0
    input.length.times do |index|
      sum += input[index].to_i % 10^index   
    end
    sum
```

one might use `inject`:

```
    input.length.times.inject(0) do |sum, index|
      sum += input[index].to_i % 10^index   
    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realised I had another fault in the code. I modified it to this: 'def sum_of_digits(i)
  input = i.to_s
  if i == 0
    return 0
  elsif input.length == 1
    return i
  else
   for i in 0...input.length
    sum += input[i].chr.to_i % 10^(i) 
    end
  end
  return sum
end' However, now the NoMethodError lies in the + sign.